# Retrieve and create Persistent entities with relations using JSON

Tags: json, rest, haskell, persistent

Haskell `persistent` library allows me to create entities with relations. I would like to be able to get entities (and also create them) using REST JSON calls. But I don't seem to understand how to approach the problem of combining a resulting entity when it is split amongst tables or how to split it when I need to save it (so that the needed parts are saved into needed tables).

An example:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Problem
  name T.Text
  description T.Text
Solution
  problemId ProblemId
  author T.Text
  solution T.Text
|]
```

So, let's say we have a single problem and multiple solutions to it. How can I get a combined information (which is a problem with all related solutions). Do I need to create a data type which could look something like this:

```
data Solution =
  Solution { author :: T.Text
           , solution :: T.Text
           }

data Problem =
  Problem { name :: T.Text
          , description :: T.Text
          , solutions :: [Solution]
          }
```

... and then define `toJSON`, so that I can send it to the caller? Or is there some other approach?

And what about creating entries in DB when I want to add a problem with several solutions (from a single REST call). How would that look like?

I hope I explained my problem correctly and you understand what I am struggling with.

Thank you

Comment: Each entity has a <EntityName>Id field that can be used to persist. I have found using unique constraints to help me query the underlying entitiy. One could also use uuid as columns to generate a unique entity for subsequent use. Also, in persistent Entity json will serialize and deserialize [json objects](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax)

Comment: To add a single problem with multiple solutions in a single call, this example should [help](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent)